# RGB to Intensity in Nodes

Tags: uv, node-editor

This time, I wish to replicate another Blender Internal process involving the RGB tab.

[image]

Here is a few examples of what I am trying to achieve in the node editor.

[image]

In this image, the UV map is using alpha transparency, but as indicated by the arrow and circle the RGB to Intensity tab is unchecked.

[image]

In this image, the tab is checked, and allows the color outline above to appear the selected color, which is pink, while leaving the black portions to disappear.

Is there a way to replicate this process using nodes in EEVEE rendering? I've tried and could not figure out the same results. If this question is already answered or is similar to another one, please direct me to it.

Answer (score 2):

This setup should replicate alpha transparency in eevee.
[image]